# Opening a BigTIFF file in Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, bigtiff

I am trying to open and extract data from a 90MB TIFF file using Python. The code I'm using is the following:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr, ogr

def get_value_at_point(rasterfile, pos):
    gdal.UseExceptions()
    gdata = gdal.Open(rasterfile)
    gt = gdata.GetGeoTransform()
    data = gdata.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float)
    gdata = None

    x = int((pos[0] - gt[0])/gt[1])
    y = int((pos[1] - gt[3])/gt[5])
    return data[x, y]
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
RuntimeError: This is a BigTIFF file.  BigTIFF is not supported by this version of GDAL and libtiff.
```

Any hints on how to overcome this? I'm using Anaconda and my GDAL version is 2.3.3 and the libtiff version is 4.0.10

Comment: Don't think it's a bigtiff when it's just 90MB

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things here:

Firstly don't set gdata to None until you are COMPLETELY done with that raster, data will return a broken dataset if you do. Please see for a more detailed explanation: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas

Next thing uninstall gdal using pip then reinstall it using the .whl file from here: 
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal
Let me know if you need an explanation how to do this.

Also 90MB is -tiny- it shouldn't need to be a bigtiff till it goes over 4GB when compressed.

Also just to make everything a bit faster/memory efficient:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr, ogr

def get_value_at_point(rasterfile, pos):
    gdal.UseExceptions()
    gdata = gdal.Open(rasterfile)
    gt = gdata.GetGeoTransform()
    x = int((pos[0] - gt[0])/gt[1])
    y = int((pos[1] - gt[3])/gt[5])

    data = gdata.ReadAsArray(x,y).astype(np.float) #This will only load the cell you want
    return data
```